# corrupted Oracle 11g database

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, recovery, corruption

At a client site with a development Oracle 11.2.0.3/linux DB

power outage and crash - no archivelog mode - no backups - Don't know how this was even running

select file#,substr(name,1,70) name, recover, status, fuzzy, checkpoint_change#,checkpoint_time, resetlogs_change#, resetlogs_time from v$datafile_header;

`FILE# NAME                                               REC STATUS  FUZ 
CHECKPOINT_CHANGE# CHECKPOINT_TIME      RESETLOGS_CHANGE# RESETLOGS_TIME
1 /oracle/oradata/orcl/system01.dbf                 NO  ONLINE             YES         4663440487 08-MAR-2018 02:57:17            945184 04-APR-2012 12:07:59
2 /oracle/oradata/orcl/sysaux01.dbf                 YES ONLINE             YES         3759618229 21-DEC-2016 22:19:41            945184 04-APR-2012 12:07:59
11 /oracle/oradata/orcl/rmdata01.dbf                 YES ONLINE             YES         3759618229 21-DEC-2016 22:19:41            945184 04-APR-2012 12:07:59`

Basic plan:

`alter database datafile 2 offline drop;
alter database datafile 11 offline drop; 
recover database ; 
export/import
rebuild DB`

Don't care about sysaux, however, I hope to keep whatever is in datafile 11.

I was hoping to force the DB open even with datafile 11 in a bad state.

Oracle says any hidden parameters will not help due to very old SCNs.

Have you faced this situation and successfully recovered the data?

Comment: The one time I tried to recover with a no archivelog mode and no backups, Oracle support closed the ticket with "Nothing can be done."

Comment: @CaM  Agreed, but just grasping for one final trick to help the client.

Comment: Your development code is in a Code Repository.  Right?

Comment: I've heard people talk about reading the data directly from disk and piecing the data together that way. Would be painful but I guess possible if you really need it.

Comment: @Bobby Durrett  Is that something you've heard through Oracle or did someone come up with their own code?

Comment: I think it was some consultant. I've done that sort of thing on a mainframe database long ago. Have to figure out where the data lies and dump out some blocks in hex then build a program to read them. There may be tools to make this easier. I think you have to really need the data to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who wants to know how this was resovled...

Bobby Durrett was correct, Oracle does have the ability to pull data from blocks.

I contacted Oracle ACS.  They sent a top consultant and using the Data UnLoader tool (DUL), which by the way is not their product, were able to extract data from the blocks that survived the corruption.

Bascially you configure the tool with a few parameters and identify the datafiles of interest.  It helps a lot if the system data file is present.  You can tell it to create SQL*Loader or dmp files.  It will skip any block that is corrupt and move on to the next block.  The datafiles are read cold so no need to mount or create a new instance or any such thing.

Caveat:
All you get is table DDL and data.  No users, contraints, FK so your are not recovering the database, just the data.

It works beautifully - on any block not corrupted!